# How to receive json values(for eg:username and password send as json from an android app) in Mvc 4 Web api

Tags: android, json, api, asp.net-mvc-4

```
**i am developing an android application that have to access a remote server.i know how to do that.but i want to know several thing point outing below**
```

*1:in my app there is sign in page.i have to check user's username and password with a remote sql server database.so i have to access the api from the server(mvc 4 web api).now i am trying to create that api.after sending the user credentials to web api i am come stuck there.because i am new to api creation i don't know how to receive it in api can anyone help me??*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) which has explained in detail, how to create ASP.Net Web API, hope that will help you to understand how to retrieve data.